# Trying to initialize an array of stuct inside a struct, but getting storage/memory pointer error

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am trying to create a voting smart contract in solidity.

But I cannot get a hand on how to initialize Vote.differentVotes in side my function createVote() :

my structs

```
    struct Vote_element {
        string name;
        uint numberOfVotes;
    }

    struct Vote{
        string title;
        address creator;
        Vote_element[10] differentVotes;
        bool done;
    }
```

the function I am having issues with.

```
    function createVote(string memory _title , string[] memory _elements) public {
        Vote storage v;

        for(uint i = 0; i < _elements.length; i++)
            v.differentVotes[i] = Vote_element(_elements[i], 0); // error here
            
        v.title = _title;          // error here
        v.creator = msg.sender;    // error here
        v.done = false;            // error here
        
        all_votes.push(v);         // error here
    }
```

I got the following error everywhere but I do not understand it.

```
This variable is of storage pointer type and can be accessed without prior assignment,
which would lead to undefined behaviour.
```

Can someone guide me ?

Comment: Which Solidity version are you using?

Comment: @PetrHejda I'm using Solidity 0.8.0.  (pragma solidity ^0.8.0). I already countered the problem by using one single struct. But I still want to know why the code above is producing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract StudentVotes {
  Vote[] all_votes;

  struct Vote_element {
    string name;
    uint numberOfVotes;
  }

  struct Vote{
    string title;
    address creator;
    Vote_element[10] differentVotes;
    bool done;
  }

  function createVote(string memory _title , string[] memory _elements) public {
    // Before initializing the variable into a struct, you must push the struct into
    // Votes' array.
    Vote storage v = all_votes.push();
    // Then you can initialize the each variable into a struct
    v.title = _title;
    v.creator = msg.sender;
    for(uint i = 0; i < _elements.length; i++)
        v.differentVotes[i] = Vote_element(_elements[i], 0);
    v.done = false;
  }

}
```